# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, frontend, jquery-events

I want the show function outside of document ready. If the time is equal to zero it has to show me the right and wrongs, but I was getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    droppableId = $(this)[0].id;
    draggableId = ui.draggable[0].id;

    var show = function(ui, droppableId, draggableId) {
        if (wordMap[droppableId].indexOf(draggableId) != -1) {
            ui.draggable.removeClass("ui-state-right").addClass("ui-state-right");
        } else {
            ui.draggable.removeClass("ui-state-right").addClass("ui-state-wrong");
        }
    }
});


var seconds = 60;

function secondPassed() {

    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60),
        remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
    }

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;

    if (seconds == 00) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "0:00";

        if (corrects >= 4) {
            $("#successAlert").show();
            $("#startAgainGameBtn").show();
        } else {
            $("#resultBtn").prop('disabled', true);
            show();
            $("#getSol").show();
        }

    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}


var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

Comment: Can you show also your HTML?

Comment: Try making `show()` a window variable so it would be `window.show = function(){}` you would then reference it using window.show

Comment: The cause of the error is that `wordMap[droppableId]` does not reference anything. What are you expecting it to be?

Comment: i was just assigning droppable id to the draggable id, so if it's match then i get correct if not then wrong

Comment: it would be great if i get any related example so i can understand and thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, as in your code you weren't passing the variables into the function hence the undefined error. This way the variables are ready for direct use in the function. However this is untested due to not having any html to test with.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var droppableId = $(this)[0].id;
    var draggableId = ui.draggable[0].id;

    window.show = function() {
        if (wordMap[droppableId].indexOf(draggableId) != -1) {
            ui.draggable.removeClass("ui-state-right").addClass("ui-state-right");
        } else {
            ui.draggable.removeClass("ui-state-right").addClass("ui-state-wrong");
        }
    }
});


var seconds = 60;

function secondPassed() {

    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60),
    remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
    }

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;

    if (seconds == 00) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "0:00";

        if (corrects >= 4) {
            $("#successAlert").show();
            $("#startAgainGameBtn").show();
        } else {
            $("#resultBtn").prop('disabled', true);
            window.show();
            $("#getSol").show();
        }

    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}


var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

Comment: actually it's a huge code it and i created draggable elements dynamically, if you want to see i will post it here